# WP Northwind for Theme Development?

Tags: customization, plugin-recommendation, theme-development, database

Is there any tool online that can quickly populate a WordPress3 database with faux information to assist in theme development? Perhaps creating 8 categories, inserting a dozen or so posts into each, adding a thumbnail for each, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just today read [Dummy Content Filler Resources](http://speckyboy.com/2010/09/26/dummy-content-filler-resources-for-wordpress-drupal-and-joomla-developers/) post that has several sets of data and plugins for WordPress listed.

Comment: Nice collection.