# Any dummy content I can use for development?

Tags: theme-development

I tried using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dummy-content/

but when I try using it, I get something like

> An error occurred: Field 'to_ping'
>   doesn't have a default valueAn error
>   occurred: Field 'to_ping' doesn't have
>   a default valueAn error occurred:
>   Field 'to_ping' doesn't have a default
>   valueAn error occurred: Field
>   'to_ping' doesn't have a default
>   valueAn error occurred: Field
>   'to_ping' doesn't have a default value

Is it the plugin or is it my WordPress (which is new? 3.0.5 just downloaded)

Perhaps there are other Dummy content available

Comment: Might wish to try the theme unit tests: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test .. for creating test/dummy content.

Comment: @t31os, this should be an answer :)

Comment: Added as an answer.. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP Northwind for Theme Development?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/wp-northwind-for-theme-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might wish to try the [theme unit tests](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) for creating test/dummy content.

Just note, some of the images in the unit test may have incorrect URLs, they were for me(but should be relatively easy to correct - i can give you the URLs if you need them, i've fixed them in my installation - i just can't remember specifically which ones right now).

Answer (score 0):

I've always used [Demo Data Creator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/demo-data-creator/) plugin.
It's a plugin that allows a WordPress developer to create demo users, blogs, posts, comments, categories and all done from a very easy admin panel.